# How to deactivate all flows via sf cli

Tags: soql, visual-workflow, metadata, sobject, tooling-api

I'm trying to deactivate all active flows via sf data cli

I saw docs said we can deactivate if via Metadata field
`You can activate and deactivate flows with the Metadata field.`
[image]

Below command is trying to get curret active, and then update it. but it cant access to Metadata field

```
flowsVersion=$(
  sf data query --query "SELECT Id, ActiveVersion.Id, ActiveVersion.MasterLabel, ActiveVersion.Status, ActiveVersionId FROM FlowDefinition WHERE ActiveVersion.Status = 'Active'" \
  --use-tooling-api --wait 10 --json  --target-org $targetOrgAlias | jq -r '.result.records'
)

# Deactive all active flows, to prepare for uninstalling package
while IFS= read -r flow; do
  flowId=$(echo $flow | jq -r '.Id')
  flowName=$(echo $flow | jq -r '.ActiveVersion.MasterLabel')

  echo "======= Deactive flow $flowName with id $flowId ======  "

  sf data update record --json --use-tooling-api --target-org $targetOrgAlias --sobject FlowDefinition --record-id $flowId --values "mns:FlowDefinition.activeVersionNumber=0"

done < <(echo $flowsVersion | jq -r -c '.[]')
```

The error said

```
  "message": "No such column 'mns:FlowDefinition.activeVersionNumber' on sobject of type FlowDefinition",
```

Comment: ah I found appropriate syntax
`sf data update record --json --use-tooling-api --target-org $targetOrgAlias --sobject FlowDefinition --record-id $flowId --values "Metadata='{\"activeVersionNumber\":0}'"`

works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah I found appropriate syntax

```
sf data update record --json --use-tooling-api --target-org $targetOrgAlias --sobject FlowDefinition --record-id $flowId --values "Metadata='{\"activeVersionNumber\":0}'"
```

works as well